# Get a thumbnail of an Image with the Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the cover of an album with an specific height and width, or, in fact, a square thumbnail generated by default in the Facebook Api.

I only get the album ID and its cover ID.

If I use `$facebook->api('/'.$cover_id)` then the API method returns me only 6 sizes of this image, but I want to get a thumbnail.

This is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try This may be this help full for you
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/